# core data unrecognized selector sent to instance error: and Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have tried below code to update an object in core data but got error.

```
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSLog(@"objects %@",objects);


    // yourIdentifyingQualifier is unique. It just grabs the first object in the array.
    AllChallenge *tempChallenge = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];


    tempChallenge =[[AllChallenge alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"tempchallenge >>>>> %@",tempChallenge);

    // update the object

    tempChallenge.status = 1;



    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

After compile I got CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'AllChallenge'. Thanks for any help.

Comment: where does `objAllChallenge` come from? Did you mean to write `tempChallenge`?

Comment: Yes, I mean tempChallenge.

Comment: The question is if you use tempChallenge or objAllChallenge in YOUR code. Not in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update an *existing* object then you should not replace it with a newly
allocated one:

```
AllChallenge *tempChallenge = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];
// tempChallenge =[[AllChallenge alloc] init]; // <-- REMOVE THIS LINE
tempChallenge.status = 1;
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

If you want to create a *new* object then you have to use the designated initializer,
or this convenience method:

```
AllChallenge *tempChallenge = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AllChallenge" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];
```